# Create one object from properties and add to collection of destination with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am surprised that I haven't found this question yet.

I have an object structure similar to the following:

```
public class Source
{
   public int SomeId {get;set;}
   public int NestedIdOne {get;set;}
   public int NestedIdTwo {get;set;}
}  

public class Dest
{
   public Dest()
   {
      this.Children = new List<Child>();
   }

   public int SomeId {get;set;}
   public IList<Child> Children {get;set}
}

public class Child 
{
   public int NestedIdOne {get;set;}
   public int NestedIdTwo {get;set;}
}
```

So the idea is that from the Source instance automapper creates a Child instance and adds it to the **Dest.Children** collection.

I have already used the following approach:

```
CreateMap<Source, Dest>().ConstructUsing(MyMethod):

private Dest MyMethod(Source mySource)
{
   //... build Dest by hand.
}
```

This works fine but I would like to know if there is a more "auto" approach.

I have tried just doing:

```
CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
CreateMap<Source, Child>();
```

but this does not work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two maps and call a child map from a parent:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Child>();

    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
        .AfterMap((src, dest, ctx) =>
        {
            dest.Children = new List<Child>();

            dest.Children.Add(ctx.Mapper.Map<Child>(src));
        });
});
```

Usage:

```
var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

Dest destination = mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(source);
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. Thanks.